# Could H₂S₂O₈ (peroxydisulfuric acid), made in the clouds of Venus, be used for making a propellant?

Tags: fuel, atmosphere, venus, oxidizer

The salts of the [peroxydisulfate ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxydisulfate), S$_2$O$_8$$^2$$^-$, are strong oxidants like the perchlorates that are used in propellants for rockets.

In [this answer on Chemistry stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119349/can-sulfuric-acid-itself-be-electrolysed/119352#119352) is a link to a [thesis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thesis) which describes the production of peroxydisulfuric acid by electrolysing concentrated sulfuric acid.

Because the clouds of Venus contain much concentrated sulfuric acid, could future missions to the atmosphere of Venus, using electrolysis of this acid to produce peroxydisulfuric acid, use this strong oxidizer to make a propellant to get back home to Earth ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem in making propellant on Venus, is surely in finding the fuel, rather than the oxidizer. Oxygen can be made by [electrolyzing $\text{CO}_2$](https://www.materialstoday.com/surface-science/news/new-catalyst-to-convert-co2-to-co/) if necessary and while $\text{S}_2\text{O}_8^{2-}$ is a very strong oxidizer, meaning that it will oxidize lots of things, the mass of the sulphur atoms means that pure oxygen is probably a better rocket fuel

Where [electrolysis of sulphuric acid](http://mychemistryyourdoubts.blogspot.com/2015/08/electrolysis-of-conch2so4-any-guess.html) might be useful is as a way to make hydrogen, which is in short supply on Venus. This could be used as fuel, or combined with $\text{CO}_2$ to [make methane and water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabatier_reaction). The water can then be electrolyzed to make more oxygen and get back some of the hydrogen.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It would be fine if you could  add some links, for instance  for the making of methane  and water out of hydrogen and CO$_2$.

Answer (score 7):

Peroxydisulfates and peroxydisulfuric acid itself would be a bad choice for rocket oxidizers for several reasons:

- H<sub>2</sub>S<sub>2</sub>O<sub>8</sub> is actually a solid with melting point of 65°C, therefore unsuitable for liquid fueled rockets,
- In pure form acid is even more aggressive and corrosive than sulfuric acid, it's like sulfuric acid on steroids. It can explode in contact with organic materials and is never shipped in pure form, rather its salts are used,
- Ammonium salt (NH4)<sub>2</sub>S<sub>2</sub>O<sub>8</sub> has a negative oxygen balance, sodium and potassium salts leave a lot of residue. Solid sulfates, and SO<sub>2</sub>, SO<sub>3</sub> gases are inevitable in exhaust, and all of those are heavy molecules. This will cause poor $I_s$$_p$ ([specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse)) and rocket performance.
- Sodium and potassium salts have a very high pressure exponent, and they tend to detonate rather than deflagrate. Mixed with metal powders like Mg, Al, MgAl alloys they can detonate unconfined on sub-gram level.

But H<sub>2</sub>S<sub>2</sub>O<sub>8</sub> can be used to produce some well known oxidizer, hydrogen peroxide H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>. Actually hydrolysis of H<sub>2</sub>S<sub>2</sub>O<sub>8</sub> was a baseline of previous industrial process for H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> production. This process suffered from heavy ions (Fe, Cr, Mn) contamination because acid used in process is very corrosive. Produced H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> was pretty unstable in higher concentrations (called HTP - high test peroxide) because heavy ions promote its decomposition. Stabilizers like sodium stannate were used to bond heavy ions and improve HTP stability. Because of stability issues process was abandoned in favor of anthraquinone process which gives much more stable H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>.